# Execute sql script and not wait for completion

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a sql stored procedure that runs for about 3 minutes, I am looking to execute this stored procedure from asp.net, but I know that if I do, that asp.net will most likely time out.

I'm thinking of just creating a job within sql to have it execute that stored procedure, and have asp.net call a stored procedure to call that job.
I have a table that is updated when the stored procedure starts, and when it ends.

My application will use this to determine when the script has finished, however, I wanted to know if there is another way to run the stored procedure and not have it wait for it to finish  to push a response back.

I just want to know if there is a more efficient way to do this, or if I should just stick to creating jobs for scripts that take forever to run.

Comment: I've used the job approach before but I think the accepted answer here is probably better... Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Storec Proc without waiting for completion.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828558/asynchronous-storec-proc-without-waiting-for-completion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this article: [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/). The articles gives code example, and explains why leveraging internal [activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx) is better than relying on a SQL Agent job. Running procedures like this is reliable (unlike the ADO.NEt async BeginExecuteXXX, the execution is guaranteed even if the client disconnects) and the execution will occur even after a SQL Server restart and even after a disaster recovery server rebuild.

Comment: I was just looking at this article as well, this seems to take care of my problem.

Thank you for the quick responses.

Comment: I m using oracle and with Oracle client i can't use Asynchronous procedure execution! so ?? creating a job within sql to have it execute that stored procedure would be the best approach ?

Comment: @frank if you have questions ask them as a separate question.

Comment: i did ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737525/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-which-start-a-job-in-asp-net-page

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like this would be a good candidate for using [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the result, you can just use the `SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery()` method. This will fire of the command on a background thread. More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se.aspx).

Comment: For this instance I am unablet o use the BeginExecuteNonQuery because I am not using an SqlCommand to execute my stored procedure, I am using DataSet Templates to manage my sql scripts, which also makes it easier to work with. But thanks !