# Calling oracle stored procedure which start a job in Asp.Net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, plsql, oracle11g

Because in a .net application which use the OracleClient one can't use the method: BeginExecuteNonQuery
which allow you to call a procedure and don't wait the end.

```
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery.aspx
```

I was thinking to create a procedure that fire a job.

```
   http://www.ulaska.com/oracle/oracle_procedure_job_submit.html
```

do you think this would works ?

Comment: any answer , comment ? suggestion ?

Comment: I just tried this. Both ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteNonQueryAsync cause the browser to wait for the procedure to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution would works

I don't see any problem with calling stored procedure (which run job) from asp.net

Comment: i will need to wait the job ends ? can you provide an example of code ?

Comment: You need to call procedure and don't wait the end of procedure execution ?